# Replacing value of a column should not update last_modified time in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have to replace the some column value to other value but it should not update the `last_modified` column

```
id  name        last_modified
1   from    10.01.2019 08:54:08
2   from    10.01.2019 08:54:08
3   from    10.01.2019 08:54:08
4   Ami     10.01.2019 08:54:08
```

To

```
id  name        last_modified
1   to      10.01.2019 08:54:08
2   to      10.01.2019 08:54:08
3   to      10.01.2019 08:54:08
4   Ami     10.01.2019 08:54:08
```

Comment: `update the_table set name = 'to' where name = 'from'`?

Comment: There seems to be a trigger (or similar) to set the `last_modified` when a column is updated. Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: during data migration I just want to change data

Comment: Then disable the trigger before migration and enable it afterwards

Comment: yes that can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a trigger on the table that sets `last_modified`, you could prevent its execution in two ways:

- Disabling the trigger:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE mytable DISABLE TRIGGER modified_trig;
  ```

  After your update is done, re-enable it:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE TRIGGER modified_trig;
  ```

  To avoid concurrent data modifications while you are running your update, run both `ALTER TABLE`s and the update in a single transaction.
- Make sure that (normal) triggers are not fired at all while you run your update.

  This can be done by running

  ```
  SET session_replication_role=replica;
  ```

  You need superuser privileges for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can  update a specific column

```
update table_name set name='to' where name='from'
```